# How can I plot multiple spectrograms on the same scale?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to plot data, and then data with noise subtracted out of it on the same scale so I can accurately compare the two. What's the best way to do this?
Right now I'm just doing:

```
f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(np.diff(rawdata), F_S)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.colorbar()

f, t, Sxx = spectrogram(np.diff(rawdata - noise), F_S)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.colorbar()
```

Where the diff is just for aesthetic reasons

Comment: I do not quite understand the problem. What is wrong with the current plot? How should it look like instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can add vmin and vmax arguments to your call to pcolormesh. Set them to the max and min value of both your datasets.
See https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html

```
f1, t1, Sxx1 = spectrogram(np.diff(rawdata), F_S)
f2, t2, Sxx2 = spectrogram(np.diff(rawdata - noise), F_S)

Sxx_min = np.amin(np.minimum(Sxx1, Sxx2))
Sxx_max = np.amax(np.maximum(Sxx1, Sxx2))

plt.subplot(211)
plt.pcolormesh(t1, f1, Sxx1, vmin=Sxx_min, vmax=Sxx_max)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.colorbar()

plt.subplot(212)
plt.pcolormesh(t2, f2, Sxx2, vmin=Sxx_min, vmax=Sxx_max)
plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: I've tried doing that, but instead everything is now a solid color and I can't tell where any of my data is.

           
    max_data = max(np.amax(rawdata), np.amax(rawdata - noise))


    min_data = min(np.amin(rawdata), np.amin(rawdata - noise))


            plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, vmin=min_data, vmax=max_data)





https://imgur.com/a/oP7be

Comment: It seems everything is zero in these figures. Could be a problem with the code or with the ranges. Some large outliers could be the problem. What are the original ranges? Do the plots without vmin/vmax look ok?

Comment: I cannot tets it without data, but you should probably not use the rawdata in the min/max functions, but the Sxx array.

Comment: Are there any nan values in Sxx1 or 2?

Comment: Had a single-color box too. In my case, I plotted the `log` of the spectrogram, meaning i have to take min of the log as well. Since my data contained zeroes, this resulted in `min` being `-infty`. Fixed it like this: `vmin = np.log(min(np.amin(spec1[spec1 != 0]), np.amin(spec2[spec2 != 0])))`.